# Why is WFM used for "working from home"?

Tags: acronyms

I've seen this used in several places, but WFH seems to make more sense to me. Is there some other significance that I'm missing besides the 'M' coming from the end of 'home'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WFH is the usual acronym for working from home, as you'd expect. WFM is Internet slang for 'Works for me'. Perhaps the two have been confused and the mistake has perpetuated.

Comment: That's teh ticket! Pwned!

Comment: That seems like a reasonable explanation

Comment: I've seen 'wfh' degenerate to 'wtf' a few times.

Comment: Am I the only person who thinks **Works for me** means *That's good enough for me*? This answer doesn't WFM.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What user3444 meant is that although “works for me (WFM)” has nothing to do with “work from home (WFH),” the two acronyms were conflated simply because WFM and WFH look similar.  This explanation makes perfect sense to me, although I do not know if it is the truth or not.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: Thanks for the clarification, but all I can say is it seems odd that 10 people upvoted this (-1 because I downvoted). This implies to me that at least *some* of them did so because they've actually encountered WFM being used with some kind of **I work for me (at home)** meaning. If not I think the question itself is pointless, and should therefore be closed anyway. And I wasn't able to find a single instance in over five minutes of Googling to support OP's suggestion that this usage might be seen "in several places". Besides, I like my own explanation better! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think that you have some misunderstanding about what this question is about.  I can easily find some instances of “work from home (WFM)” on Google, and it is obvious that some people consider WFM stands for “work from home.”  The question asks why they do.  See also Anguish Languish’s comment.  I do not know if that is a real story or not, but confusing the acronyms “wfh” and “wtf” is perfectly plausible even though no one uses “what the f**k” when they mean “work from home.”

Comment: Tsuyoshi Ito: I have to take your word for it that several/many people really do use the "acronym" this way, but that doesn't explain *why*. It's always possible that **one** person **once** made a "mistake" that others copied without knowing why. But to suppose that they all do it because of confusion with the equally-obscure WFH seems unlikely to me. People who actually work from home aren't usually stupid, so why would they mix these things up so meaninglessly? By comparison, an ironic "I've been 'Workforce Managed'*" seems a far more obvious derivation to me, even if I'm a lone voice.

Comment: ...also note that Anguish Languish’s comment is totally irrelevant. WFH is at best a rare combination of letters , and there will be many people who type "wtf" (what the fuck) repeatedly in internet chat contexts. Once the first letter is typed, given the proximity of the other letters on the keyboard, fingers are inclined to just repeat what they usually do it that general area. Which doesn't transpose to wfh/wfm because no-one types *either* of these very often, so there's no mechanism for the fingers to "learn" an automatic sequence involving just them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think you have confused WFH and WFM in your comments, and that is the point.  It seems that WFM is a common word, at least among software developers.  Therefore, it is quite understandable that what Anguish Languish described happened in some of them between WFH and WFM.

Answer (score 6):

WFM: work from **mobile** — not necessarily home, but off site.

Comment: This seems to be entirely reasonable. Do you have any reference you can link to?

Answer (score 0):

Working From Mobile is far more probable now that WiFi and mobile hot spots (LTE) are so pervasive in North America.

Comment: Hi, Just Some Guy. Your response would make a very reasonable comment beneath Jack Brosch's answer, but it is a bit thin as a standalone answer. Can you take up Andrew Leach's challenge to Jack Brosch to point to reference-work authority supporting the claim that WFM stands for "working from mobile"?